# Limit of a solution to a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits

Pick a positive real $p$ and $a\geq 1$. Let $y_n$ be the solution to
$$y'_n(t)=-n^pt^{p-1}y_n(t)^a+n^{p/2}t^{p/2-1}, \quad y_n(1/n)=0.$$
If $a=1$, then for all $t\geq \frac{1}{n}$, $\lim_{n\to \infty}y_n(t)=0$. I would like to prove that it is also true for $a\geq 1$. Any idea please ?

Comment: First show us your ideas!

Comment: First, I try to forget the second term in the right-hand side, then I can solve the ODE and get the limit. As I said, I also try the linear case, since I can solve it. Then I try to compare it to standard equation, such that Ricatti or Bernoulli but I didn't conclude.

Comment: I know that $y_n\geq 0$. My intuition was the following: the minus is very important. I try to use a stopping time :$\tau=\inf\{ t, y_n(t)\nrightarrow 0 \}$. Then, there is a $\delta>0$, such that $y_n(\tau)>\delta$ (up to an extraction). So I can conclude that $\lim_{n\to \infty} y'_n(\tau)=-\infty$. And then ? I don't know

Comment: @Cesareo
Edit: there exists $(\tau_k)\to \tau$ such that $y_n(\tau_k)\nrightarrow 0$. But then the $\delta$ depend on $n$..
So maybe, we can take $\delta>0$ and $\tau=\inf \{ t, \inf_n y_n(t)>\delta\}$, but it turns around..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $y_n(t) \ge 0$, if $\{\max_{t\gt\frac 1n}y_n(t)\}\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ then $y_n(t)\to 0$. If $y_n(t)$ is differentiable, then at the maximum we have $y'_n(t)=-n^pt^{p-1}y_n(t)^a+n^{p/2}t^{p/2-1}=0$ and
$t^* =\arg\max_{t\gt\frac 1n}y_n(t)$ and $y_n(t^*) = (n t^*)^{-\frac{p}{2a}}$ hence $\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n(t)\to 0$

Comment: Thank you, I did not look at it this way. It looks quite easy now!